# How to query firebase database to return an angularfirelist from an array of ids

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angularfire2, ionic4

I have an object that has a property whose value is a list of ids.

```
const obj = { list: ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3'] };
```

Currently, this is all I'm able to do. But it returns an array of Observables.

```js
// Class variable...
records: Observable<Record>[];

constructor(private afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {}

getRecords () {
  this.records = obj.list.map(id => this.afDB.object(`path/to/collection/${id}`));
}
```

Having `this.records` as an array of `Observable`'s does not seem the best for use in the template, unlike an `Observable` of an array.

I would rather have `records: Observable<Record[]>` than `records: Observable<Record>[]`.

Is there anyway to pass those id's along as part of the query function to angularfire database instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something likes this:

```
afDB.collection('yourCollection', ref => ref.where('id', '==', 'yourId'));
```

Found this on https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Comment: I'm using the realtime database and not the firestore. And btw, that form of querying only accepts one id.

Comment: In this case it would work like this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: I know how that works but that would require that I make 3 separate requests, which is why I'm trying to find out if there's another way of doing such

Comment: You could get all ids an then filter like this array.filter(x => obj.list.includes(x)  ); In any case the filtering will happen after you loaded all the data of a collection

Comment: Do you mind updating your code to reflect what you mean?